# Automatically set added properties when retrieving database objects in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am extending a large C# project that connects to SQL Server.

In the database I have an Inventory table which has a foreign key manufacturer_id from the Manufacturer table.

I have added some properties to the Inventory class from the Manufacturer table because the app must continue to send Inventory objects but now include Manufacturer information as well.

```
public partial class Inventory
{
    public string ManufacturerName {get; set;}
}
```

In my InventoryRepository I now call my SetManufacturerName method whenever I return Inventory objects and must remember to call it in any new methods.

Is there a way to call a method automatically whenever an Inventory object is retrieved from the database?

I am unable to change anything in the database.

Comment: How do you connect to SQL Server ? An ORM ? Plain SQL / ADO .NET ? Some more info about your architecture would be helpful.

Comment: What ORM are you using to map from DB to your class?  LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, nHibernate, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your desired method in the constructor of the class. It will ensure that whenever an instance of object is created your method is called

```
      public partial class Inventory
      {
         public Inventory() { YourMethodCall(); }
         public string ManufacturerName {get; set;}
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call anything upon object creation, just provide a non-trivial implementation of the property

```
 public string ManufacturerName
 {
    get
    {
        // your code here,e.g.
        return this.Manufacturer.Name;
    }
    ...
 }
```